# problem with calling a javascript function through php

Tags: javascript, php

this is my source code

```
echo "<script>";
echo "movea(".$rejected.",".$total.")";
echo "</script>";`
```

whenever i try to run this code , html compiler ignores everything that is ahead of this code and also the required goal is not achieved as function is not being called.
if I remove those variable from the code and pass values manually it works fine.
what is the problem please help.
both the variable are of int type.

Comment: Because it renders with two strings that are not quoted probably. Look at what is rendered, not the PHP code and you will see your problem. Or look at the console for the JavaScript error.

Comment: No need to exit PHP to print variables in double quotes. but you need to quote the strings within JS - use single quotes for that; `echo "movea('$rejected', '$total')";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<script>";
echo "movea(\"".$rejected."\",\"".$total."\")";
echo "</script>";
```

the var's aren't quoted properly.

Comment: Why not just use single quotes inside the string? Then you don't need to escape the inner quotes (and you can use string interpolation instead of concatenation, but that's just a matter of preference).

Answer (score 0):

Check your quotes inside the movea function. Even if your variables are of type int you can still pass them as string in JS.

```
echo "movea('".$rejected."','".$total."')";
```